# How do I sort through an array of buttons to see if only one is left enabled?

Tags: javafx

How do I sort through an array of buttons to see if only one is left enabled? I am creating a Sudoku solver and need to check if there is only one button left unselected in each row, column, or box and if it is to highlight the last remaining option. I can't find a command that will allow me to check each individual cell in the row to see if ONLY one is left. This is what I have so far

```
public class SudoHelper extends Application

{




public boolean [][][] DisabledCell = new boolean[3][9][9]; // Creates our array
Scene scene;
Pane pane;
Pane main;
BookMark bane;

@Override
public void start (Stage primaryStage)
{
    for(int a = 0;a<3;a++)
    {
        for(int b=0;b<9;b++)
        {
            for(int c=0; c<9;c++)
            {
                DisabledCell[a][b][c]=false;
            }
        }
    }
    mouseClicks = new MouseEvent[0];
    SmartCell[] currentGame = new SmartCell[81];
    pane = new Pane();
    pane.setPrefSize(684, 702);
    int x,y;
    x=y=0;
    main = new Pane();
    for(int i=0; i<81; i++)
    {
        currentGame[i]= new SmartCell(i);
        currentGame[i].setLayoutX(x);
        currentGame[i].setLayoutY(y);
        pane.getChildren().add(currentGame[i]);
        x+=76;                                      // Sets the layout for out array of SmartCells
        if(x==684)                                  // and puts our additional buttons on the screen
        {                                           // With our scene and stage
            x=0;
            y+=78;                  
        }           
    }

    main.setPrefSize(1100, 702);
    main.getChildren().add(pane);
    bane= new BookMark();
    scene = new Scene(main);
    main.getChildren().add(bane);
    bane.setPrefSize(416, 702);
    bane.setLayoutX(685);
    bane.setLayoutY(0);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Sudoku Helper");
    primaryStage.show();


}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Application.launch(args);       // Starts the game


}
class BookMark extends Pane
{
    class List
    {
        String[] MyList=new String[0];
        public void Add(String Add)
        {
            if(this.MyList.length>0)
            {
            String[] Resize = new String[this.MyList.length+1];

            for(int i=0;i<this.MyList.length;i++)
            {
                Resize[i]=this.MyList[i];
            }
            Resize[this.MyList.length+1]=Add;
            }
            else
            {
                this.MyList = new String[1];
                this.MyList[0]=Add;
            }
        }
        public void Clear()
        {
            this.MyList = new String[0];
        }
    }

    Button lkm = new Button("Load Bookmark"); // Creates our load bookmark button
    Button bkm = new Button("Save Bookmark"); // Creates out save bookmark button'
    final ToggleGroup group1 = new ToggleGroup();
    final ToggleGroup group2 = new ToggleGroup();
    RadioButton rl1a = new RadioButton("Rule One All"); // Creates rule one radiobutton
    RadioButton rl1s = new RadioButton("Rule One Click");   // Creates Rule one click radiobutton
    RadioButton rl2s = new RadioButton("Rule Two Click");   // Creates rule two click radiobutton
    RadioButton rl2a = new RadioButton("Rule Two All"); // Create rule two radiobutton

               void ruleTwo()
       {

       }
       void ruleOne()
       {

            int _x,_y;
            int B=10;
            String[]Getloc = name.split("~");
            int loc = Integer.parseInt(Getloc[1]);
            _y = loc%9;
            if(loc<8) // checking which row we are looking at
            {
                _x=0;
                for(_x=0; loc<8;)
                {
                    if()
                            {

                            }
                }
            }

            else if(loc<18) 
            {
                _x=1;
            }
            else if(loc<27) 
            {
                _x=2;
            }
            else if(loc<36) 
            {
                _x=3;
            }
            else if(loc<45) 
            {
                _x=4;
            }
            else if(loc<54) 
            {
                _x=5;
            }
            else if(loc<63) 
            {
                _x=6;
            }
            else if(loc<72) 
            {
                _x=7;
            }
            else 
            {
                _x=8; // checks blocks were looking at
            }

            if(_y>=0&&_y<=2) // checks which block we are in
            {
                    if(_x>=0&&_x<=2)
                    {
                        B=0;
                    }
                    else if(_x>=3&&_x<=5)
                    {
                        B=1;
                    }
                    else if(_x>=6&&_x<=8)
                    {
                        B=2;
                    } 
                }
                else if(_y>=3&&_y<=5)
                {
                    if(_x>=0&&_x<=2)
                    {
                        B=3;
                    }
                    else if(_x>=3&&_x<=5)
                    {
                        B=4;
                    }
                    else if(_x>=6&&_x<=8)
                    {
                        B=5;
                    }
                }
                else if(_y>=6&&_y<=8)
                {
                    if(_x>=0&&_x<=2)
                    {
                        B=6;
                    }
                    else if(_x>=3&&_x<=5)
                    {
                        B=7;
                    }
                    else if(_x>=6&&_x<=8)
                    {
                        B=8;
                    } 
                }


       }
       BookMark() // Our buttons specifications (Location font ect)
       {


           this.bkm = new Button("Save Bookmark");
           this.lkm = new Button("Load Bookmark");
           this.bkm.setFont(Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR, 12));
           this.bkm.setLayoutX(10);
           this.bkm.setLayoutY(10);
           this.lkm.setFont(Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR, 12));
           this.lkm.setLayoutX(150);
           this.lkm.setLayoutY(10);
           this.rl1a.setLayoutX(10);
           this.rl1a.setLayoutY(250);
           this.rl2a.setLayoutX(10);
           this.rl2a.setLayoutY(500);
           this.rl2s.setLayoutX(250);
           this.rl1s.setLayoutY(250);
           this.rl1s.setLayoutX(250);
           this.rl2s.setLayoutY(500);
           this.rl1a.setFont(Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR, 12));
           this.rl1s.setFont(Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR, 12));
           this.rl2a.setFont(Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR, 12));
           this.rl2s.setFont(Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR, 12));
           this.group1.getToggles().add(this.rl1a);
           this.group1.getToggles().add(this.rl1s);
           this.group2.getToggles().add(this.rl2a);
           this.group2.getToggles().add(this.rl2s);
           BookMark.this.getChildren().add(this.lkm);
           BookMark.this.getChildren().add(this.bkm);
           BookMark.this.getChildren().add(this.rl1a);
           BookMark.this.getChildren().add(this.rl1s);
           BookMark.this.getChildren().add(this.rl2a);
           BookMark.this.getChildren().add(this.rl2s);

          // bkm.setOnMouseClicked(e -> Save(e));




       }
}
private MouseEvent[] mouseClicks;
class SmartCell extends StackPane
{
    GridPane buttonPane;
    Pane valPane;
    Text textVal;
    Button [] btn;
    String name;
    SmartCell(int nameint)
    {
        buttonPane = new GridPane();
        btn = new Button[10];
        for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            btn[i] = new Button(i+""); // Turns i into a String
            btn[i].setFont(Font.font("Ariel", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.REGULAR, 12));
            btn[i].setOnMouseClicked(e -> mouseHandler(e));
            buttonPane.add(btn[i], (i-1)%3, (i-1)/3);



        }

        // When the user clicks one of the 9 buttons, we want to take the number of the button
        // they clicked, and set the text on the text pane to that number, hide the 9 buttons, 
        // and show the text pane.
        name = "SmartCell~"+String.valueOf(nameint);
        textVal = new Text(25, 55, "");
        textVal.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 48));
        textVal.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        valPane = new Pane();
        valPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color:black; -fx-border-stroke-width:1");
        valPane.getChildren().add(textVal);




        getChildren().add(buttonPane); // Add the pane with the 9 buttons to the cell
        getChildren().add(valPane);    // Add the pane with the one piece of text to the cell
        buttonPane.setVisible(true);   // We start out showing the 9 buttons
        valPane.setVisible(false);     // ...NOT showing the pane with the single text

    } // end constructor



    void disqual(MouseEvent e)
    {
        MouseEvent[] ResizeMouse = new MouseEvent[SudoHelper.this.mouseClicks.length+1];
        ResizeMouse[ResizeMouse.length-1]=e;
        SudoHelper.this.mouseClicks = ResizeMouse;
        int _x,_y;
        int B=10;
        String[]Getloc = name.split("~");
        int loc = Integer.parseInt(Getloc[1]);
        _y = loc%9;
        if(loc<8) // checking which row we are looking at
        {
            _x=0;
        }
        else if(loc<18) 
        {
            _x=1;
        }
        else if(loc<27) 
        {
            _x=2;
        }
        else if(loc<36) 
        {
            _x=3;
        }
        else if(loc<45) 
        {
            _x=4;
        }
        else if(loc<54) 
        {
            _x=5;
        }
        else if(loc<63) 
        {
            _x=6;
        }
        else if(loc<72) 
        {
            _x=7;
        }
        else 
        {
            _x=8; // checks blocks were looking at
        }

        if(_y>=0&&_y<=2) // checks which block we are in
        {
                if(_x>=0&&_x<=2)
                {
                    B=0;
                }
                else if(_x>=3&&_x<=5)
                {
                    B=1;
                }
                else if(_x>=6&&_x<=8)
                {
                    B=2;
                } 
            }
            else if(_y>=3&&_y<=5)
            {
                if(_x>=0&&_x<=2)
                {
                    B=3;
                }
                else if(_x>=3&&_x<=5)
                {
                    B=4;
                }
                else if(_x>=6&&_x<=8)
                {
                    B=5;
                }
            }
            else if(_y>=6&&_y<=8)
            {
                if(_x>=0&&_x<=2)
                {
                    B=6;
                }
                else if(_x>=3&&_x<=5)
                {
                    B=7;
                }
                else if(_x>=6&&_x<=8)
                {
                    B=8;
                } 
            };  
            int CellNum =Integer.parseInt(((Button)e.getSource()).getText());
            if(DisabledCell[0][_x][CellNum-1]==true||DisabledCell[1][_y][CellNum-1]==true||DisabledCell[2][B][CellNum-1]==true)
            {
                disqualify(Integer.parseInt(((Button)e.getSource()).getText()));
                return;
            }
            DisabledCell[0][_x][CellNum-1]=true;
            DisabledCell[1][_y][CellNum-1]=true;
            DisabledCell[2][B][CellNum-1]=true;
            textVal.setText(((Button)e.getSource()).getText());
            buttonPane.setVisible(false);
            valPane.setVisible(true);

            for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)disqualify(i); // Since we have locked in, all others are out of play
            // in this cell
            int c = 0;
            int z = 0;
            switch(B)
            {   // Figures out which block our selected number is in.
            case 0: z=0;
                break;  // ^
            case 1: z=27;
                break;  // ^
            case 2: z=54;
                break;  // ^
            case 3: z=3;
                break;  // ^
            case 4: z=30;
                break;  // ^
            case 5: z=57;
                break;  // ^
            case 6: z=6;
                break;  // ^
            case 7: z=33;
                break;  // ^
            case 8: z=60;
                break;  // ^

            }
            for(int w = 0; w<9; w++)
            {

                Object xob =SudoHelper.this.pane.getChildren().get((_x*9)+w);
                SmartCell d =SmartCell.class.cast(xob); // Disqualifies x cells
                d.disqualify(CellNum);
                xob=d;
                Object yob =SudoHelper.this.pane.getChildren().get(_y+(9*w));
                SmartCell b =SmartCell.class.cast(yob); // Disqualifies Y Cells
                b.disqualify(CellNum);
                yob=b;
                Object zob =SudoHelper.this.pane.getChildren().get(z+c);
                SmartCell a =SmartCell.class.cast(zob);
                a.disqualify(CellNum); // Disqualifies boxes
                zob=a;
                c++;
                if(c==3)
                {
                    z+=9;
                    c=0;

                }
            }




    }
    void mouseHandler(MouseEvent e)
    {
        // When any button gets clicked, we take the text from the button, put it on the Text
        // shape, hide the pane with the 9 buttons, and show the text pane, making it look like
        // the 9 buttons have "gone", and the new value that we have "locked in" has taken their place.
        //

        if(e.getSource() instanceof Button)
        {
            // If this was a right click, then just disable this button; If it was a left click then lock
            // in the value this button represents.
            if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY)
            {
                disqualify(Integer.parseInt(((Button)e.getSource()).getText()));
                // disables button after clicked
                return;
            }
            // System.out.print("A button was clicked"); // for debugging

        disqual(e);
        }   // end if source was a button
        }   // end mouseHandler

    void disqualify(int buttonNo)
    {
        // When we are called, we disable button #buttonNo in this cell
        btn[buttonNo].setDisable(true);
        btn[buttonNo].setStyle("-fx-base:black; -fx-text-fill:black; -fx-opacity:1.0"); // Sets color of cells and numbers after disabled.
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        // The toString representation of a cell is a string containing a list of 
        // the values "still in play" --- the remaining candidate values --- for the cell
        //
        // Start with an empty string. Visit all 9 buttons, and if a given button is
        // not disabled (i.e still in play), then add its number (from the text on the 
        // button) to our string
        //
        String result = "";
        for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
            if(!btn[i].isDisabled())
                result += i;
        return result;

    }
}

       private boolean[] InitalizeTile() // Initalizes our board of 81 cells
       {
           boolean[] newbool = new boolean[81];
           for(int i=0; i<81; i++)
           {
               newbool[i] = false;
           }
           Random R = new Random();
           for(int j=0; j<0; j++)
           {
               while(true)
                   {
                        int W = R.nextInt(81);
                        if(newbool[W]==false)
                        {
                            newbool[W]=true;
                            break;
                        }
                   }
           }
           return newbool;
       }

}
```

Comment: Please post code which is relevant to the problem you are asking about.  You haven't even got an array of buttons in the code.  See [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to post code which is both minimal (only demonstrates the issue at hand), and complete (a self-contained application which can be complied and run after copy and paste without modification).

Comment: I resubmitted my code with the more helpful code

Comment: Yes, it's more helpful, but it's also really long.  The idea with an mcve is you strip the code down to only the minimal code needed to demonstrate the issue at hand while still maintaining a complete executable program.

Comment: All I really need to know is how to look at an array of buttons and see if only one is left enabled

Answer (score 0):

> All I really need to know is how to look at an array of buttons and see if only one is left enabled.

```
Arrays.stream(buttons).filter(button -> !button.isDisabled()).count() == 1
```

Sample application:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class DisabledButtonCount extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button[] buttons = {
                new Button("1"),
                new Button("2"),
                new Button("3")
        };

        buttons[1].setDisable(true);
        buttons[2].setDisable(true);

        System.out.println(
                "Only one button enabled? " +
                        (Arrays.stream(buttons).filter(button -> !button.isDisabled()).count() == 1)
        );

        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```